# How to draw linechart with lines going backwards with achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to draw lines with achartengine that don't need to always increment x value. But the engine seems to reorder all the points and connect them sorted by their x value.

For example when I'm trying to draw a circle:

```
double x = Math.cos(count);
double y = Math.sin(count);
graph.add(0,count, x, y);
angle += (2*Math.PI)/32; 
count++;
```

A radiator is drawn each time the graph is repainted, even if I use the option to set manually the index on the XYSeries.

Is there any way to block this reorganization or simply skip it?

Comment: The internal AChartEngine model does the sorting for performance purposes. However, I don't recommend you to use a charting library in order to draw circles.

Comment: the circle drawing is just an example. In fact I just want to draw a rect that can go backwards through x. Like drawing a Z.